# comparing two files with different columns

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i have the two files(count.txt, count1.txt). i need to do the following
1. get the values from count.txt and count1.txt where 1st column is equal.
2. if its equal need to compare the 2nd column like ((1st column value + 5) >= 2 column value)

count.txt

`order1,150`
`order2,165`
`order3,125`

count1.txt

`order1,155`
`order2,170`
`order3,125`
`order4,123`

and i want the output like below,

Output.txt

`order1,155`
`order2,170`

i have used below nawk command for the 1st point, but not able to complete the 2nd point. Please suggest to achieve the same.
`nawk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} ($1 in a)' count.txt count1.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nawk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) && (a[$1]+5)<=$2' count.txt count1.txt
```

Comment: Hi @glenn , thanks for the reply. But this `nawk` is not working. Below is the output,
order1,155
order2,170
order3,125

Comment: Probably `(a[$1]+5)>=$2` should be replaced by `$2>=(a[$1]+5)`

Comment: I went by your specifications rather than the the requested output.